# local host has been blocked by cors policy request header field content type is not allowed by access control

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, rest, asp.net-core-5.0

In asp.net core 5 I am using services for getting data and posting data to database. I got this error when posting object of list to service.
error 1.Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:35020/api/ApiDisplay/InsertDetails' from origin 'http://localhost:47717' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
angular.js:15697
erorr 2. Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","processData":false,"crossDomain":true,"contentType":"application/json","url":"http://localhost:35020/api/ApiDisplay/InsertDetails","dataType":"json","data":{"CustomerID":"114","CustomerName":"Sridhar","Address":"Nalgonda","StateId":"1","CityId":"","LandMark":"CrossRoad","Mobile":"1541454145"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}.

I am getting id easily in services but not this object. In console.log i got data. In alert it shows object:object.

this is my controller

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

```
    public IActionResult InsertDetails([FromBody] CustomerDetail cd)
    {
        var result = disrep.InsertDet(cd);

        if (result.Count() > 0)
            return Ok(result);
        else
            return NoContent();

        //cd = result;
        //return cd;
    }
```

this is my code in .js file

```
    this.insertdetails = function (Customer) {

    alert('insertdetails');
    var request = $http({

        method: "POST",
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType:"application/json",
        url: baseUrl + "/api/ApiDisplay/InsertDetails",           
        dataType: "json",
        data: Customer,


    });
    return request;
}
```

in startup.cs

```
        services.AddCors(options =>

        {

            options.AddPolicy(allowSpecificOrigins,

            builder =>

            {

                builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:47717")

                        .AllowAnyHeader()

                        .AllowAnyMethod();

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Put this code to the top of ConfigureServices

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

           ........... 
            
        }
```

app.UseCors should be placed between app.UseRouting() and app.UseAuthorization()

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
            .....

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseAuthorization();

            ....
      }
```

if it is working then try to  replace

```
 builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
```

with

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:47717")
```

Comment: no progress with your changes.